# Kofax "edit table header" not allowing second page navigation of a single document

Tags: kofax

It has been more than a week, i have tried almost all option on Kofax Total Agility 7.6 "*Transformation Designer*"

I have a requirement of:

- Locating and Extracting the table content of a document(English or French)

To be able to do that i follow steps:

1. Open "*Transformation Designer*"
2. Created an extraction project, attached a sample document (having 5 pages)
3. Navigate to *project settings->Table tab*
4. Trying to create new "*table header pack*"

### When i am trying to train system for header and non header lines, i am unable to navigate from pages of a same document, the image-viewer screen is showing only first page of a selected document and there is no next page button/navigation, only next document button/navigation is available.

Note: All training material covers only single page document where extraction is quite straight forward

### Exact question is *How should someone train "table header pack" when table is on the second or third page of a document*

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not received anything from forum about the same. So in my case i will create zone, for each Table Cell than map it to table schema by code: Internal or External

Answer (score 0):

I have been in the same situation and resolved it by changing the sample multi-page image into single page Tiff images. The you can create a doc with the table starting on page 1. When you test you'll find that it still finds the table starting on the nth page.

E.g. KTA comes with the Repository Browser (separate installation) which allows you to export documents as single-page Tiff images.